# Postgres Index usage patterns

Tags: postgresql

I am a newbie to Postgres, we are on postgres version 11.8
There are many indexes on few of the important tables, we would like to identify index usage pattern.
We want to store results of the attached query into a table and run it every 4 hrs for a period of 2 weeks.

Can we baseline decision of dropping indexes based on the query results ?

```
    WITH table_scans as (
    SELECT relid,
        tables.idx_scan + tables.seq_scan as all_scans,
        ( tables.n_tup_ins + tables.n_tup_upd + tables.n_tup_del ) as writes,
                pg_relation_size(relid) as table_size
        FROM pg_stat_user_tables as tables
),
all_writes as (
    SELECT sum(writes) as total_writes
    FROM table_scans
),
indexes as (
    SELECT idx_stat.relid, idx_stat.indexrelid,
        idx_stat.schemaname, idx_stat.relname as tablename,
        idx_stat.indexrelname as indexname,
        idx_stat.idx_scan,
        pg_relation_size(idx_stat.indexrelid) as index_bytes,
        indexdef ~* 'USING btree' AS idx_is_btree
    FROM pg_stat_user_indexes as idx_stat
        JOIN pg_index
            USING (indexrelid)
        JOIN pg_indexes as indexes
            ON idx_stat.schemaname = indexes.schemaname
                AND idx_stat.relname = indexes.tablename
                AND idx_stat.indexrelname = indexes.indexname
    WHERE pg_index.indisunique = FALSE
),
index_ratios AS (
SELECT schemaname, tablename, indexname,
    idx_scan, all_scans,
    round(( CASE WHEN all_scans = 0 THEN 0.0::NUMERIC
        ELSE idx_scan::NUMERIC/all_scans * 100 END),2) as index_scan_pct,
    writes,
    round((CASE WHEN writes = 0 THEN idx_scan::NUMERIC ELSE idx_scan::NUMERIC/writes END),2)
        as scans_per_write,
    pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) as index_size,
    pg_size_pretty(table_size) as table_size,
    idx_is_btree, index_bytes
    FROM indexes
    JOIN table_scans
    USING (relid)
),
index_groups AS (
SELECT 'Never Used Indexes' as reason, *, 1 as grp
FROM index_ratios
WHERE
    idx_scan = 0
    and idx_is_btree
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Low Scans, High Writes' as reason, *, 2 as grp
FROM index_ratios
WHERE
    scans_per_write <= 1
    and index_scan_pct < 10
    and idx_scan > 0
    and writes > 100
    and idx_is_btree
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Seldom Used Large Indexes' as reason, *, 3 as grp
FROM index_ratios
WHERE
    index_scan_pct < 5
    and scans_per_write > 1
    and idx_scan > 0
    and idx_is_btree
    and index_bytes > 100000000
UNION ALL
SELECT 'High-Write Large Non-Btree' as reason, index_ratios.*, 4 as grp 
FROM index_ratios, all_writes
WHERE
    ( writes::NUMERIC / ( total_writes + 1 ) ) > 0.02
    AND NOT idx_is_btree
    AND index_bytes > 100000000
ORDER BY grp, index_bytes DESC )
SELECT reason, schemaname, tablename, indexname,
    index_scan_pct, scans_per_write, index_size, table_size
FROM index_groups
order by 3, 1;
```

Comment: You should instead study the explain plans of the major queries which are running on your Postgres instance.  Based on that, decide whether the current indices be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the suggestion. How can we capture explain plan when major queries are running.  Are there any system tables which captures explain plan.

Comment: That's not typically how you do this.  The explain plan will give estimates as to what will actually be happening production when the queries run.  You would only resort to your current approach if production performance, for some reason, seemed to be radically different than what the explain plan suggested.

Comment: The volume of data in production and non-production environments have high variation and also the type of jobs which run in production can't be replicated. As suggested in my initial post, can I baseline my index usage by storing the results to a table and drop unused/low-used indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify most used indexes with the command lines belows and clean the database :

```
SELECT * FROM pg_statio_all_indexes;

SELECT * FROM pg_stat_all_indexes;

SELECT indexrelid::regclass,pg_relation_size(indexrelid::regclass) FROM pg_index;
```

Also is possible to identify non indexed foreign keys with the query below:

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass,conname,reltuples::bigint,indkey,conkey ,CASE
WHEN conkey && string_to_array(indkey::text, ' ')::SMALLINT[] THEN FALSE
ELSE TRUE END as might_require_index
FROM pg_constraint JOIN pg_class ON (conrelid = pg_class.oid) JOIN
pg_index ON indrelid = conrelid WHERE contype = 'f';
```

for identifying tables withouth primary key  :

```
     SELECT conrelid::regclass,conname,reltuples::bigint,indkey,conkey ,CASE
WHEN conkey && string_to_array(indkey::text, ' ')::SMALLINT[] THEN FALSE
ELSE TRUE END as might_require_index
FROM pg_constraint JOIN pg_class ON (conrelid = pg_class.oid) JOIN
pg_index ON indrelid = conrelid WHERE contype = 'f';
```

Indexes overlap:

```
WITH index_info AS
(SELECT pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid) AS index_def, indexrelid::regclass
index_name , indrelid::regclass table_name, array_agg(attname) AS index_att
FROM
pg_index i JOIN
pg_attribute a ON i.indexrelid = a.attrelid
GROUP BY pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid), indrelid, indexrelid)
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE WHEN a.index_name > b.index_name THEN a.index_def
ELSE b.index_def END AS index_def,
CASE WHEN a.index_name > b.index_name THEN
a.index_name ELSE b.index_name END AS index_name,
CASE WHEN a.index_name > b.index_name THEN b.index_def
ELSE a.index_def END AS overlap_index_def,
CASE WHEN a.index_name > b.index_name THEN b.index_def
ELSE a.index_def END AS overlap_index_name,a.table_name
FROM index_info a INNER JOIN index_info b ON (a.index_name != b.index_name
AND a.table_name = b.table_name AND a.index_att && b.index_att );
```